# subgroups of order 20 of $\displaystyle \ \mathbb{Z_{40}} \times\mathbb{Z_{50}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to know 'efficient(or rapid)' method

> counting the number of
>
> subgroups of order **20** of    $\ \mathbb{Z_{40}} \times\mathbb{Z_{50}} $

$$
\
$$
Actually I've found out the number of

subgroups of order 5, 10, 15, 25 of
$ 
\ \mathbb{Z_{40}} \times\mathbb{Z_{50}}
$

(with comparative ease)
$$
$$
BUT in case of order **20**... it's not easy to me :-(

$$
$$
Please give me some hand.

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: I've done in case of 'order 5' like this //// 1st, # of elements of order 5 ->> 24 //// because subgroup of order 5 is cyclic, 24/phi(5) is # of subgroups of order 5 ///

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
G:= \mathbb{Z}_{40}\times \mathbb{Z}_{50} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}
$$
Note that
$$
20 = 4 \times 5
$$
So any abelian group of order 20 must be
$$
H_1 := \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_5 \text{ or } H_2 := \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_5
$$
You can now "fit" the $H_i$'s into $G$ as follows :
$$
H_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \langle 4\rangle \times \mathbb{Z}_5\times \{0\}
$$
or
$$
H_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \langle 4\rangle \times \{0\} \times \langle 5\rangle
$$
Each such fit will give you a different subgroup. Can you finish this process?

Comment: The two "fits" mentioned are not a complete list.

Comment: @vadim123: I know. The answer was meant to give the OP the basic idea to work out the rest of the options.

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyan  : Thank you very much. I've followed your method, and I think the answer is that.....# of subgroups isomorphic H1 : 6  and # of subgroups isomorphic H2 : 12 ... // Is this right? Could you check my answer, please?